# Open embedded draw.io with only part of the palettes

Tags: draw.io

I am using draw.io in embeded mode in iframe, using the draw.io code installed locally.
Draw.io enbles the option to hide sidebar palletes using +moreshapes button on the bottom left corner of the app.

How can I configure it progrematically. using url parameters, or my own plugin, or any other way.

Many tx

Answer (score 0):

On my plugin I have change the libraries on localstorage.

```
Draw.loadPlugin(function (ui) {
        var config = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('.drawio-config'));
        config.libraries = "general;basic;arrows2;";
        localStorage.setItem('.drawio-config', JSON.stringify(config))
    }
```